# Not getting the required SOAP request XML

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, client

I am working on a Simple php Client that uses OCPP (Open Charge Point Protocol). I have created the client and This is the request XML that goes from my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/">
      <env:Header>
          <ns1:chargeBoxIdentity env:mustUnderstand="true">XXX01</ns1:chargeBoxIdentity>
          <ns1:Action env:mustUnderstand="true">/Authorize</ns1:Action>
          <ns1:MessageId env:mustUnderstand="true">123</ns1:MessageId>
          <ns1:RelatesTo>relatesTo</ns1:RelatesTo>
          <ns1:From/>
          <ns1:ReplyTo/>
          <ns1:To/>
      </env:Header>
      <env:Body>
          <ns1:authorizeRequest>
          <ns1:idTag>1234567</ns1:idTag>
          </ns1:authorizeRequest>
      </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
```

But I am suppose to get this XML output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?> 
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns1:chargeBoxIdentity mustUnderstand="true">XXX01 </ns1:chargeBoxIdentity>
        <ns1:Action mustUnderstand="true">/Authorize</ns1:Action>
        <ns1:MessageId mustUnderstand="true">123</ns1:MessageId>
        <ns1:RelatesTo>relatesTo</ns1:RelatesTo>
        <ns1:From />
        <ns1:ReplyTo />
        <ns1:To />
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:IdTag>1234567</ns1:IdTag>
    </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

Notice that my code has `env:Envelope` and output has `ns0:Envelope` and in my code extra attribute is there in the Soap Body. I have very limited knowledge in php SOAP. The relevant code is below.

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);

$wsdl_centralsystem = "OCPP_centralsystemservice_1.5_final.wsdl";
$params =  "0.1.1.255.0.0.1.0.";

$vLocation = "linktoserver/server.php";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_centralsystem, array(

    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
    "location" => $vLocation,
    "trace"=>1, "exceptions"=>0,

));

$chargeboxid = "XXX01";
$action = "/Authorize";
$msgid = "123";
$relatesto = "relatesTo";


//Create Soap Headers
$headerCchargeBoxIdentity = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'chargeBoxIdentity', $chargeboxid, true);
$headerAction = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'Action', $action, true);
$headerMessageId = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'MessageId', $msgid, true);
$headerRelatesTo = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'RelatesTo', $relatesto, false);
$headerFrom = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'From', NULL, false);
$headerReplyTo= new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'ReplyTo', NULL, false);
$headerTo = new SoapHeader("urn://Ocpp/Cs/2015/10/", 'To', NULL, false);

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($headerCchargeBoxIdentity,$headerAction,$headerMessageId,$headerRelatesTo,$headerFrom,$headerReplyTo,$headerTo));


$output = $client-> __soapCall('Authorize',array($params));
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided the prefixes match up with the `xmlns` declarations on the `Envelope` element, then it is valid XML and therefore valid SOAP so you should be fine. However, XML is case sensitive and I notice that your code has and `idTag` element in inside the `Body` element rather than the `IdTag` element in the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

According to OCPP specs, your current output is closer to what's correct but still has many problems.

- The full OCPP URN you're using ends with `.../2015/10/` which is for OCPP 1.6 but in your code, you're using WSDL for OCPP 1.5 which requires `.../2012/06/` for URN.
- Per OCPP spec, camel-case `idTag` is correct field name for `Authorize` message.
- You need the root tag `<authorizeRequest />` in the SOAP body.
- You need WSA (addressing) namespace `xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"` for addressing fields (`MessageId`, `From`, `To`, `ReplyTo`, `RelatesTo` and `Action` in the SOAP header.
- `chargeBoxIdentity` belongs to OCPP URN namespace.
- `MessageId` should be `MessageID` and it should not have `mustUnderstand` attribute.
- `Action`, `To`, `ReplyTo` and `chargeBoxIdentity` should have `mustUnderstand="true"` attribute. Others should not.
- As of OCPP 1.6 `ReplyTo` is required and should always have the value `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous`
- `RelatesTo` is required for responses only. This is a request.

Final version of the expected output should be like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
        xmlns:cs="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2012/06/"
        xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <soap:Header>
        <cs:chargeBoxIdentity soap:mustUnderstand="true">XXX01</cs:chargeBoxIdentity>
        <wsa:Action soap:mustUnderstand="true">/Authorize</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>123</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:From><wsa:Address>http://from-endpoint</wsa:Address></wsa:From>
        <wsa:ReplyTo soap:mustUnderstand="true"><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address></wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:To soap:mustUnderstand="true"><wsa:Address>http://to-endpoint</wsa:Address></wsa:To>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <cs:authorizeRequest>
            <cs:idTag>1234567</cs:idTag>
        </cs:authorizeRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

*Note: I've set a bit meaningful namespace prefixes, you can set anything you like.*