# Asynchronous PHP SOAP server send Acknowledgement message before response?

Tags: php, soap

I am not certain how to do this. The specs for the SOAP service I am writing says it needs to send back an acknowledgement message even before it responds with the requested response to the request.

How is this done in PHP? I have seen no examples of how to do this.

**From the requirements doc:**

> One acknowledgement message is sent by Integration Partner to Vendor
>   for every SubmitInv message request.  A single acknowledgement message
>   is also sent by Vendor to the Integration Partner from every
>   RequestInv message respons

*This is NOT a standard TCP ack response. It is a custom SOAP formatted response that is their acknowledgement that the request was received.* See example below.

**After questioning the vendor:**

> They claim that it is a legacy system and it was written to process in
>   that flow. They cannot, at this time, change it.  I told him that in
>   20+ yrs programming, I have NEVER seen any SOAP system require an ACK.
>   He claimed that it had to do with  having to "wait" for the responses.
>   Apparently they don't understand how to properly handle stateless
>   processing.

I have already attempted to do it using the PHP Output Buffering functions as outlined below by FoxVSky, it does not work in a SOAP transaction.
**Also, the standard SOAP library, the one built-in to PHP, nor the Zend SOAP library have a feature to do this.**

**Example:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <PAddRs>
      <RqUID>f11958c8-3fde-42ca-bd94-94fdfca316ef</RqUID>
      <PKey>46dba062-2105-4851-831f-a1d364741329</PKey>
      <AppStatus>
        <AppStatusCode>Accept</AppStatusCode>
      </AppStatus>
    </PAddRs>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: what is the exact wording? are you sure they don't mean they need some sort of ping endpoint to check connectivity status?

Comment: `One acknowledgement message is sent by Integration Partner to Vendor for every SubmitInv message request. A single acknowledgement message is also sent by Vendor to the Integration Partner from every RequestInv message response.`

Comment: This is in a payment integration context or something else?

Comment: No, inventory searches for vendors.

Comment: The service will handle a `RequestInv` request and respond to the request with a `SubmitInv` response.

Comment: That is how i would achive that: `SOAP req (SOAP consumer) -> ACK (SOAP server) [service is online, req is fine/is not fine and is beeing processed] -> ACK (SOAP consumer) [ready to recive response] -> SOAP response (SOAP server)`

Comment: Are you sure that's the application level requirement, not transport? (I'm talking about ACK in TCP connection)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, see my comment above from the specs. I assume they are talking about ASYNC.

Comment: @MB34, You can put the call into Gearman task for example, and use runTasks which is blocking by nature. That way you can receive the actual response via callback from GearmanClient with the data, and wrap it up nicely inside Gearman’ instead of doing forking and thread management yourself. As it seems there will be two connections established via server, over first you will receive the Ack (it will be closed after that) and data over second connection. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857402/how-soap-supports-asynchronous-call-while-rest-does-not)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, what is Gearman? This is PHP and I cannot install extensions.

Comment: @MB34, I was under the impression that you want to consume such service, while you’re writing one yourself. Since you’re creating one yourself I don’t think any of the existing implementations of SOAP server in PHP let you do that. You will have to create a middleware that does this kind of trick and then do a callback on a fixed URL of the client.

Comment: Although I stand corrected - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185128/not-getting-the-required-soap-request-xml - dig into the header attribute Reply-To.

Comment: Do you think I could implement a "fire-and-forget" ASYNC cURL call to send the ACK while still processing the request, returning as normal? I really am worried that this is not going to be an option using PHP. I know it can be done using .Net but we don't want to have to put the service up in an IIS host.

Comment: What about proxy between you and other side? Proxy receives request, send ACK and sends request to you. You receive it and return response normally (with receiving possible ACK from their side as response).

Comment: Are you sure about sending ACK **while** doing the method? I doesn't seems to me. As far as I understand, `Vendor` makes a request of `SubmitInv` on `Integration Partner` and the response is an ACK, and vice versa but with `RequestInv` request. I guess the `SubmitInv` request is used for "saving" things into the `Integration Partner` and `RequestInv` is used for getting things from it.

Comment: I'm going to clarify this with the vendor today as, in over 20 yrs of programming, I have never seen a SOAP system require an ACK.

Comment: @MB34 have you clarified this?

Comment: Somewhat. They claim that it is a legacy system and it was written to process in that flow. They cannot, at this time, change it. I told him that in 20+ yrs programming, I have NEVER seen any SOAP system require an ACK. He claimed that it had to do with having to "wait" for the responses. Apparently they don't understand how to properly handle stateless processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have implemented the acknowledgement messaging in my SOAP service, here is how it is called from the client:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$options = array();
$options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
$options['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;
$client = new Zend\Soap\Client("http://localhost/soap/server.php?wsdl", $options);

try {
    // Currently loading example request
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('RequestExample.xml');
    $t_xml = new DOMDocument();
    $t_xml->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $xml = $t_xml->saveXML($t_xml->documentElement);
    $response = $client->ReqInv($xml);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = 'Exception: '. $e. "\n"; 
}
echo $response;
```

And my service:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require(__DIR__ . '/PTResp.php');

use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover;
use Zend\Soap\Server;
use Zend\Soap\Wsdl;

class PT {
    /**
     * function ReqInv
     * Function to return the inventory for the passed request.
     * 
     *  @param string $request 
     *  @return string
     */
    function ReqInv($request) {
        $pt = new PTResp($request);
        return $pt->toString();
    }   
}

if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $wsdl = new AutoDiscover();
    $wsdl->setUri('http://localhost/soap/server.php');
    $wsdl->setClass('PT');
    $wsdl->handle();
} else {
    $server = new Zend\Soap\Server('http://localhost/soap/server.php?wsdl');
    $server->setClass('PT');
    $server->setEncoding('ISO-8859-1');
    $server->handle();
}
```

And my class (in PTResp.php):

```
class PT {

    function __construct($xml) {
        $this->m = new Mustache_Engine;
        $this->xml = @simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $this->xml->registerXPathNamespace(<my namespace info>);
        $this->SendAck();
        $this->BuildResponse();
    } // function __construct

    /*
    * This is the function that is actually called to return the response to the client.
    */
    function toString() {
        $domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $domxml->formatOutput = true;
        $domxml->loadXML($this->response);
        $this->response = $domxml->saveXML($domxml->documentElement);
        return $this->response;
    } // function toString    

    function SendAck() {        
        $this->Status = "Accept";
        $xml_post_string = $this->m->render(
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <soap:Body>
                <ProcurementAddRs xmlns=MyNamespaceInfo">
                    <RqUID>{{RqUID}}</RqUID>
                    <PKey>{{PKey}}</PKey>
                    <ApplicationStatus>
                        <ApplicationStatusCode>{{Status}}</ApplicationStatusCode>
                    </ApplicationStatus>
                </ProcurementAddRs>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>', array("RqUID" =>$this->RqUID, "PKey"=>$this->PKey, "Status"=>$this->Status));
        $url = 'http://localhost/soap/gotit.php'; // in this test, it writes the response to a file. I will be sending it to the endpoint from here
        $this->curl_post_async($url, $xml_post_string);
    } // function SendAck

    function curl_post_async($url, $post_string){
        $parts=parse_url($url);

        $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
            isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
            $errno, $errstr, 30);

        $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
        $out.= "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n";
        $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
        $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    } // function curl_post_async  

    function BuildResponse() {
        $this-response = "<XML response that is built goes here>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I flagged it for moderator assistance as FoxVSky modified his answer to use basically the same technique I posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Here my example usage

soapserver.php:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
fwrite($fp, "\n");

class MySoapServer {

    public function addNumbers($num1, $num2) {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }

}

$options = array('uri' => 'http://test.local/');
$server = new SoapServer(NULL, $options);
$server->setClass('MySoapServer');

ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
$server->handle();
$soapXml = ob_get_contents();
$size = ob_get_length();
// Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
header("Content-Length: $size");
echo $soapXml;
ob_end_flush();
// Unless both are called !
flush();
// Continue do another process after sent message
//example
sleep(10);
fwrite($fp, "Test Writing\n");
fclose($fp);
```

?>

soapclient.php:

```
<?php

// client
$options = array(
    'location' => 'http://test.local/stack/soapserver.php',
    'uri' => 'http://test.local/stack/soapserver.php'
);

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
echo $client->addNumbers(3, 5); //  8
```

You'll immediately see response `8` in broswer. After 10s, you'll see `Test Writing` in file data.txt

Comment: Can you redo this to show how to do it in a SOAP transaction? I would hate for you to get the bounty for this answer.

Comment: If you will be using standard SoapServer, you can insert call to its handle method at the place of echoing test string. (http://php.net/manual/ru/soapserver.handle.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, I fail to see what you are saying, here.

Comment: @FoxVSky, Your solution does not work in a SOAP transaction, even if you didn't show how to use it.

Comment: I am saying that his example can be used with stock standard SoapServer to achieve what’s youre after in a slightly different manner.

Comment: This solution has already been tested with unsatisfactory results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a SOAP service, why not simply use the [SoapServer](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) along with the [handle()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php) method? You shouldn't need to actually implement the TCP handshake (sending `ACK`) and what not. I'm pretty sure that's all handled for you in those classes/methods.

The context is lacking, so this is my best educated guess.

Comment: Can you please explain further? The handle() method only takes the request XML as a parameter..

Comment: I'm not following. Do you want me to explain you how the `handle()` method works?

Comment: No, I want you to explain what you mean. I KNOW how the handle method works, you are implying to use it to process the ACK and it just isn't mean to do that.

Comment: The content is not lacking as the comments on the original question get deeper into the reasons.

Comment: You should edit your question then, and add other relevant information that was discussed in the comments in order for people to help you out.

Like I stated, you shouldn't need to handle the protocol nitty gritty stuff. I'm not even sure how you would do that in PHP, unless you start opening sockets. What I'm saying is that there's already a SOAP server class that should take care of all those things for you.

Comment: What is required is not standard SOAP, so why do you think that the standard SOAP class *should* handle it?

Comment: TCP, which the standard SOAP (or any other application protocol, for that matter) uses, handles that transparently.

I have now read all the comments and to be honest, that's a very messy implementation.

SOAP is application layer, while to send an `ACK` you'll have to deal with the transport layer (TCP).

Comment: I'm sorry but you just aren't getting it. This is NOT a standard TCP ack response. It is a custom SOAP formatted response that is their acknowledgement that the request was received.