# How to implement OCPP protocol with SOAP in php?

Tags: php, soap, pahocpp

I need to integrate the OCPP connection with SOAP in php. I found a lot of examples with OCPP & JSON, but nothing with OCPP & SOAP. Can anyone please share few examples if possible? Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185128/not-getting-the-required-soap-request-xml

Comment: @ChrisWhite i am the newer to OCPP. so i need step by step  guideness

Answer (score 0):

Recommend use Json instead of SOAP. Json is most light and more fast.

But if you want to use SOAP with PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path, array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'connection_timeout' => 8,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace' => 1
    )
);
```

then

```
$call = $client->remoteStartTransaction(array(
        'connectorId' => $connectorId,
        'idTag' => $idTag
    )
);
```